# How does Parity decide which account to use when migrating a contract?

Tags: parity, truffle-migration

Parity 1.7.6

Three accounts active, two have funds.

Am migrating a contract using truffle.

Parity UI prompts me for the password for one of the accounts with funds.  Why did it choose this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default for use by any application.

Go to APPLICATIONS and PERMISSIONS and toggle all accounts visible for external applications (blue bar = active and visible) and click the star to select a default (the direct answer to your question is: the yellow star)!